# Realm: Map JSON to Realm-Objects with Alamofire

Tags: swift, realm, alamofire

I would like to use Realm and Alamofire to map JSON to my database objects. Are there good tutorials out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm offers built-in limited capabilities of mapping arbitrary JSON structures to `RLMObjects`. But there are some good third-party libraries, which could assist you with your use-case. You might want to checkout these:

- [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON) (Objective-C), which offers a declarative, Mantle like way of defining your mapping
- [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm) (Swift), which offers Realm and Alamofire support

Comment: Unfortunately they do not describe at ObjectMapper how to persist the data in realm after it has been mapped. Shouldn't there be a write transaction?

Comment: You just need to adopt Object and Mappable protocols on your class. It will be ready to be used on Realm (update, create, read as usually)

Comment: Here is an other which is easy to use: https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/tree/master/Source/Realm