# Save JSON Dictionary To Realm Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdictionary, realm

I'm using Realm to save data from my server using a JSON Response. However I've difficulty to save the dictionary to a Realm Object. My data looks like this:

```
"stuff": {
   "id": 1,
   "icon_image": [
     {
       "photo": "http://myserver.com/image/1.png"
     }
   ],
   "photo": "http://myserver.com/image/header.png",
   "thumbnail_image": [
     {
       "photo": "http://myserver.com/image/3.png"
     }
   ]
 }
```

How can I save it as Realm Object? In Realm it's possible only save primitive types. I can manage to save objects like string or float.

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479733/realm-map-json-to-realm-objects-with-alamofire) maybe help you

Answer (score 1):

To save that explicit type of data in Realm, you'd need to implement model subclasses something along the lines of these:

```
class Image: Object {
    dynamic var photo = ""
}

class Stuff: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var photo = ""
    let iconImage = List<Image>()
    let thumbnailImage = List<Image>() 
}
```

Like Đinh Quang Hiếu said in the comments, it's then up to you to 'map' the results of this JSON string to Realm. In very simple cases, you can use `Object.init(value: dictionary)` to map a Swift dictionary to Realm, but it's safer to use more fully-featured libraries like [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm) that can handle different scenarios where the JSON didn't come exactly how your app was expecting it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) to parse the JSON response into an object that swift can manipulate and then save that using Realm?

Comment: Swift's [Foundation can natively parse JSON](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization), so no need for this specific third-party to solve the issue.